# How to get NSMutableArray specific objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdate

I want to this array list bellow Sunday and Monday text object get and save in another array. other words  Get object with date and week day name both are get and save in array

Please help how can I do this. i am so tried but do not get correct answer.

```
   NSDateComponents *components;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"25-11-2016"];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"7-12-2016"];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy, EEEE"];

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

int days = [components day];



for (int x = 0; x <= days; x++) {
    [mutable_ary addObject:[dateFormat stringFromDate:startDate]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:startDate]);

     startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24)];

}
NSLog(@"%@",mutable_ary);

{
"25-11-2016, Friday",
"26-11-2016, Saturday",
"27-11-2016, Sunday",
"28-11-2016, Monday",
"29-11-2016, Tuesday",
"30-11-2016, Wednesday",
"01-12-2016, Thursday",
"02-12-2016, Friday",
"03-12-2016, Saturday",
"04-12-2016, Sunday",
"05-12-2016, Monday",
"06-12-2016, Tuesday",
"07-12-2016, Wednesday"
 }
```

Output:

```
 {

"27-11-2016, Sunday",
"28-11-2016, Monday",
"04-12-2016, Sunday",
"05-12-2016, Monday",
 }
```

Comment: Let's see what you have so far.

Comment: @ElTomato please check my updated question

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @shallowThought please check updated question

Comment: Please also post the expected result. I do not really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: firstly i get all days between two dates, then i want to all days mutable array in find specific  days. like : all Sunday, Monday

Comment: please see ones my updated question and compare NSLog array and Output array. so i want to Output array

Comment: @shallowThought please replay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"25-11-2016, Friday",
                           @"26-11-2016, Saturday",
                           @"27-11-2016, Sunday",
                           @"28-11-2016, Monday",
                           @"29-11-2016, Tuesday",
                           @"30-11-2016, Wednesday",
                           @"01-12-2016, Thursday",
                           @"02-12-2016, Friday",
                           @"03-12-2016, Saturday",
                           @"04-12-2016, Sunday",
                           @"05-12-2016, Monday",
                           @"06-12-2016, Tuesday",
                           @"07-12-2016, Wednesday", nil];

NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (id element in  arrList){
    NSString *str = element;
    if ([str containsString:@"Monday"] || [str containsString:@"Sunday"]){
        [result addObject:element];
    }
}

// print result
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: Thanks for give your precious time. and thanks a lot , your help's through solve my problem. I get specific days. thankyou so much :)

Comment: Are you there? Please solve my one more problem related this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *input = @[@"25-11-2016, Friday",
                   @"26-11-2016, Saturday",
                   @"27-11-2016, Sunday",
                   @"28-11-2016, Monday",
                   @"29-11-2016, Tuesday",
                   @"30-11-2016, Wednesday",
                   @"01-12-2016, Thursday",
                   @"02-12-2016, Friday",
                   @"03-12-2016, Saturday",
                   @"04-12-2016, Sunday",
                   @"05-12-2016, Monday",
                   @"06-12-2016, Tuesday",
                   @"07-12-2016, Wednesday"];

NSMutableArray *days = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[@"Sunday",@"Monday"]];
NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSString *day in days){
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@",day];
                          NSArray *filtered = [input filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [output addObjectsFromArray:filtered];
}

NSLog(@"%@",output);
```

Comment: I have using a NSMutableArray

Comment: One more error show bellow : what is arrayofDay and what is OrignalArray

Comment: original array is the input array . I edited the to arrayofDay to days

Comment: you are adding filter on the original array of your input array and that filter is checking if each element in the "originalArray" contains the strings in days array

Comment: NSArray* filtered  in error : Initializing 'NSArray *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

Comment: edited my whole solution, checked it and it works for me

Comment: Thanks for give your precious time but vandana is solve my problem. thankyou